# Reference Firefox add-on's install.rdf em:version in xul file

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a working add-on.  I am trying to fix a few small things.  One thing I noticed was that some XUL files use a static string of the install.rdf's `em:version`.  One instance was typoed, and it generally annoys me to maintain one version string in multiple places.  I want a solution such that I can change the `em:version`, and use code to pick that string up in XUL files to insert into options.xul `<dialogheader description="version">` tag.  Another XUL file uses a `<vbox> <text value="version">`, so I'd like to reuse the same code and technique there as well.

I've seen some examples of using JavaScript to access add-on version strings, but nothing explained how to reference that string from within an XUL element's attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access the value from within your XUL file, but need to get the version with some Javascript and then set XUL attributes and/or text with the regular Javascript DOM APIs, so something along the lines of:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID("your-addon@id", function(addon) {
  document.getElementById("version-header").setAttribute("value", addon.version);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Where might this Javascript live?  If I have `file.xul` and a similarly named `file.js` already exists and holds related code, can I just put it in the `file.js`?

Comment: Sure. I'd keep the number of script files to a minimum (performance), so just adding to an existing file would be actually a good thing.

Comment: Actually, this answer made no sense to me whatsoever at the time.  A few weeks later, after learning more, I came to revisit this question, and understand much better.  The XUL-based add-on must define the version in the install.rdf file.  It is also common to include the add-on version in an About panel, and possibly on the Options panel.  The old add-on I am working on had it in all 3 places; in-line in XUL.  Moving to a common DTD file would have been one step closer.  But pulling the version directly from the browser which got it from the install.rdf is better.  Put into a common JS file.

Comment: To be fair, when this add-on was originally written over a decade ago, I do not think there was an AddonManager.jsm or resource:// imports.  All this time it was just never touched until I came along to revive the project.  But this is definitely the way to keep it centralized.  There may be considerable overhead with this method, compared to hard coding in-line, but it is negligible in the grand scheme of things, and the payoff is not having to worry about a sloppy UI experience because you forgot to update a version somewhere, and time saved.  This is definitely a good technique.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon.  I keep getting `TypeError: AddonManager.getAddonById is not a function`  Trying in FF 29 and FF46.  Reduced to its minimum: `function onLoad ( ) { Components.utils.import( 'resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm' ); AddonManager.getAddonById( '{GUID}', function( addon ) { console.log( addon.version ); } ); }`  I am just trying to send the version to console log for testing, to rule out any other problem.  Ah!  Now I see the problem, `getAddonByID` both uppercase `ID`, not `Id` (uppercase `I` lower case `d`).  DOM uses getElementsById, easy to confuse.

Comment: @user314159 the function name is actually 'getAddonByID' (uppercase D in ID), sorry for the confusion.